# Where hashed page table is stored

Tags: operating-system, paging

What I understand is we can't guarantee large amount (larger than page size) of contiguous memory. If size of page table itself is large enough that can't be stored in 1 page that is a problem. So we again do paging on page table what is called multilevel page table. But multilevel page table is not a good choice if address is greater than 32 bit because more leveling cost most computation.

To avoid this hashed page table is used.

From my understanding hashed page table [indexable] size should be under page size. So for large address size there is going to be lots of collisions. If page size is 12 bit page table consist 2^52 entries and hashtable size is going to 2^12 ( approx don't know the exact calculation) and then per index 2^40 sized linked list. So how is this going to be feasible. So my assumption is hashtable is going to store using other methods or elsewhere. Operating system concepts book dint explain much about it and others sites also.

I have read operating system concepts ninth edition page 380.

Comment: You're overstating the use of hashed page tables. Few processors use them.

Comment: Description is updated.

Answer (score 0):

> What I understand is we can't guarantee large amount (larger than page size) of contiguous memory.

Why? Often a physical memory manager has to be able to handle the allocation of physically contiguous buffers for (some) device drivers.

> So we again do paging on page table what is called multilevel page table. But multilevel page table is not a good choice if address is greater than 32 bit because more leveling cost most computation.

Why? Most CPUs use multilevel page tables; and then have a TLB ("translation look-aside buffer") to avoid the cost of looking things up in the page tables. Modern 80x86 goes further and also has higher level paging structure caches (in addition to TLBs).

> From my understanding hashed page table [indexable] size should be under page size. So for large address size there is going to be lots of collisions. If page size is 12 bit page table consist 2^52 entries and hashtable size is going to 2^12 ( approx don't know the exact calculation) and then per index 2^40 sized linked list. So how is this going to be feasible.

The thing is; if the translation isn't in the hash table (e.g. because of limited hash table size) usually the CPU generates a fault to ask the OS for assistance, and the OS figures out the translation and shoves it into the hash table (after evicting something else from the hash table to make room). Of course the OS will probably use its own multilevel page table to figure out the translation (to shove into the hash table); so the whole "hash table" thing ends up being a whole layer of annoying extra bloat (compared to CPUs that support multilevel page tables themselves).

Comment: The source of the poster's confusion: "I have read operating system concepts ninth edition page 380."

Comment: @user3344003: I think you're right. I found a copy of that book and did a brief scan through pieces of it, and everything seems a little off (it's like an archer who hits the target but never hits the bullseye).

Comment: That book creates more question from confused students than any other. And it costs a fortune.